# Empty header sections (python-docx)

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I am trying to modify word documents using python-docx. Everything is working fine for the documents' body sections, but it gets trickier for the header sections, which I currently am not able to access.

Below is the code I've executed for trying to read the content of the header sections in my document.

```
import os
from docx import Document

os.chdir('/Users/rtsg/Desktop/Docx')
document = Document('report_v1.docx')

sections = document.sections
for section in document.sections:
    header = section.header
    for paragraph in header.paragraphs:
        print(paragraph.text)
```

When trying to print the content of the header sections, I get nothing returned (empty strings I guess).

Did someone experience a similar issue and managed to solve it ? Are there some workarounds for modifying the content of the header section ?

Comment: Looking at the Python docs, I think this page is what you're looking for https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/header.html - the most pertinent content: "There are three header properties on Section: .header, .even_page_header, and .first_page_header" (This corresponds to the information freeflow provided, but that was the "interop", not the Python library which is why it was of no use to you.)

Comment: Instead of `print(paragraph.text)` try `print('paragraph.text == "%s"' % paragraph.text)`. That way you'll be able to tell the difference between no paragraphs and blank ones.